# Show Error: The upload path does not appear to be valid

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am try to upload a image by php codeigniter but show "The upload path does not appear to be valid."

This Action is performed in xampp server and window 10

```
public function do_upload($username) {
    $config = array(
        'upload_path' => "./assets/images/",
        'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg",
        'overwrite' => TRUE,
        'max_size' => "2048000", 
        'max_height' => "768",
        'max_width' => "1024"
    );
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        print_r($data);
    } else {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        print_r($error);
    }
}
```

This code i used i chek many time but i not found error
What error in the code,
If i use this same code in other project it will work but not in the main project , Please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: I mean, the error message is pretty clear.  You are trying to upload to a path that either doesn't exist, or to which your application does not have permissions to write.

Comment: i think u need to replace `'upload_path' => "./assets/images/"` with `'upload_path' => "assets/images/"`

Comment: I already doing it but not work

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter you should always try and use the constant `APPPATH` to find the application folder.

`APPPATH` is the best because it dynamically retrieves the proper filesystem directory structure no matter which operating system you are on. This ensures that all file paths in your code are going to be correct.

However if you are not trying to get to the `Application` folder. You can use the `FCPATH` constant which dynamically points to the front controller of your application.

You are getting this error because the path to your /assets/images folder is not valid. You need to MAKE SURE that the path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

first you should check you have created folder assets/images folder in root directory because in config this path is defined

```
$config = [
         'upload_path' => "./assets/images/",
        'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg",
        'overwrite' => TRUE,
        'max_size' => "2048000", 
        'max_height' => "768",
        'max_width' => "1024"
  ];
  $this->load->library('upload',$config);
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div style="color:red;" class="error">', '</div>');
  if$this->upload->do_upload()){
    $img = $this->upload->data();
    $img_name = base_url('uploads/'.$img['file_name']);
    $data = $this->input->post();
    $data['image_path'] = $img_name;
    unset($data['submit']);
    return $this->flash_message(
            $this->articlemodel->add_article($data),
            'Article added sucessfully',
            'Article added to failed'
    );   


   }
   else
   {
    $upload_error = $this->upload->display_errors;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to resolve

1. If directory inside the application folder

   ```
   application -> assets -> images 

   'upload_path' => APPPATH. 'assets/images/';
   ```
2. If directory outside of the application folder

   ```
   root folder -> assets -> images

   'upload_path' => FCPATH. 'assets/images/';
   ```

Comment: @RaviKantSharma add project directory structure in question

Comment: localhost/project/assets/images/ fro to upload file

Comment: this code only not working in a project but it work in all

Comment: Can be permission problem ?

Comment: Try to make directory like this `if (!file_exists('path/to/directory')) {
    mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true);
}`